# Why would Postgres replication skip field data for an update?

Tags: postgresql, replication

The understanding is replication via the postgres WAL would send the:

- operation-type eg' `update`, `insert` and `delete`
- schema-name
- table-name
- data - all the fields of the table currently

The postgres verison being used:

```
PostgreSQL 14.5 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit
```

What was seen is that fields where the data is `null` - would not send in the data from the replication.
Otherwise if the field had contents in the fields would send.

However in one case for a specific `json` field - if no change was made to that field in an update - the field would not be sent.

The issue here is that the assumption is that a field not sent is null - so the application will clear the field on the system listening to the replication changes.

Why would Postgres replication skip field data for an update?

Comment: Are you talking about logical replication from PostgreSQL to PostgreSQL?  The WAL does not contain SQL statements at all. We need more details to get an idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Think it is called logical replication (also seeing streaming replication that seems to be the same thing). [Psycopg](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#replication-protocol-support) is used to create a replication slot and listen for WAL events and put these events on a kafka queue (for change data capture). What is in the question is what is published on the kafka queue. Let me investigate what the process is seeing directly from the WAL and update.

Comment: This would be determined by the logical replication decoding plugin you are using, which presumably is not the built-in one.